# How can I prefill value in a custom form field in a ModelForm

Tags: python, django, custom-fields, modelform

Let's say I have a model as follows.

## models.py

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    middle_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True, null=True)
```

And I have a custom field `email` as follows in a ModelForm

## forms.py

```
class ProfileForm(ModelForm):
    email = forms.CharField()
    class Meta:
         model = models.Profile

    fields = ('email', 'middle_name')
```

In the am setting an instance of the above mentioned modelform so the data is prefilled in the form for an edit template as follows.

## views.py

```
def edit_profile(request):
    profile = models.Profile.objects.get(user=request.user)
    profileform = forms.ProfileForm(instance=profile)
    return render_to_response('edit.html', { 'form' : 'profileform' }, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Now in the form I get all the values prefilled for all the fields under Profile model but the custom fields are empty and it makes sense.

but is there a way I can prefill the value of the custom fields ? maybe something like:

```
email = forms.CharField(value = models.Profile.user.email)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Can I suggest something else? I'm not a huge fan of having that `email` field within a ModelForm of `Profile` if it has nothing to do with that model.

Instead, how about just having two forms and passing in initial data to your custom one containing `email`? So things would look like this:

## forms.py

```
# this name may not fit your needs if you have more fields, but you get the idea
class UserEmailForm(forms.Form):
    email = forms.CharField()
```

## views.py

```
profile = models.Profile.objects.get(user=request.user)
profileform = forms.ProfileForm(instance=profile)
user_emailform = forms.UserEmailForm(initial={'email': profile.user.email})
```

Then, you're validating both the profile and user email form, but otherwise things are mostly the same.

I assume you are not sharing logic between the Profile ModelForm and this UserEmailForm. If you need profile instance data, you could always pass that in there.

I prefer this approach because it's less magical and if you look back at your code in a year, you won't be wondering why, in brief scanning, why `email` is part of the `ModelForm` when it does not exist as a field on that model.

Comment: I do agree with you, it really does not make sense to have email field within the modelform. Though, in my case the scenario is a little different. Also, i was just reading the documentation of `inital` and it seems helpful in my case. Thanks for your response :)

Comment: Cool, I was just making assumptions but if it helped, that's awesome! Happy coding.